# Array matching in ElasticSearch

Tags: arrays, postgresql, elasticsearch

I have been trying to re-work some AcoustID code, and I am trying to figure out if ElasticSearch has a way to fuzzy-match arrays of ints. Specifically, say I have my search array: `{1,2,3}` and in ES, I store my reference docs:

```
1: {3,4,5,6}
2: {1,1,1,2,4,3,4}
3: {6,7,8}
4: {1,1,2,3}
```

I would want to get 4 back as the best match (it contains 1,2,3 exactly) then 2 (it contains my search but has an extra int in there), then 1 (it has a 3) but NOT 3.

The current AcoustID code does this in postgres with some custom C code -- if it's helpful for context, it can be found here; https://bitbucket.org/acoustid/pg_acoustid/src/4085807d755cd4776c78ba47f435cfb4b7d6b32c/acoustid_compare.c?fileviewer=file-view-default#acoustid_compare.c-122

I actually intend to have ~100GB of these arrays indexed, with each containing ~100 ints. Can ES handle this kind of work, and provide a reasonable level of performance?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to us the [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) of Elasticsearch. This query will give you back the required documents.

However, using it on an integer array will give you a different sorting, as the fieldNorms are not stored along with integer fields. 
To get your desired sorting, it would be enough to store your integer array as string array and query with the terms query:

```
"query": {
    "terms": {
      "ids": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ]
    }
  }
```